# Create Table with VBA or Pivot Table off of multiple tabs with same data (cannot PowerPivot)

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a large amount of data that I am trying to pivot for several lists that are then used to create several dashboards. Because of how it needs to be shared across organizations, the data needs to reside in the Workbook (cannot create external Access database). Given the number of rows to evaluate, the raw data is spread across multiple tabs, but since the tables aren't interrelated (they're essentially the same table with the same values, just different dates) I cannot PowerPivot. I also tried to create a table using the Sumif function and a static list of dates, which works for one of the tables I need but for the others, I need a way to create a pivot table with dynamic dates.

Is there a VBA option to essentially consolidate specific data elements like a Pivot table using the data across multiple tabs?

Comment: How manty rows total approximately?

Comment: So far I'm up to 3.25M

Comment: Have you tried something like this:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-pivottable-3ae257d2-ca94-49ff-a481-e9fc8adeeeb5   ?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't recreate a "normal" pivot table so to speak. There isn't appropriate flexibility to choose specific fields that you want to display and in what order.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach but I have no idea how well it would work with that much data.

It uses ADO and sql to combine the data into a single recordset, and uses that recordset as the pivotcache source.

```vb
'added reference to ADO 2.7 library
Dim sql As String, strFile, strConn, pc As PivotCache, pt As PivotTable
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile & _
         ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

cn.Open strConn
'combine all source sheets
sql = "Select * from [Sheet4$] union all select * from [Sheet5$]"

rs.Open sql, cn

Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlExternal)
Set pc.Recordset = rs 'use recordset as source data

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(tabledestination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot").Range("B2"))
pt.PivotFields("Col1").Orientation = xlRowField
pt.PivotFields("Col2").Orientation = xlColumnField
pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("Col3"), "Sum of Col3", xlSum
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim! Looks like it's too much data and it's not processing, but I apprecaite the help!

Comment: I think you're really pushing the limits with that much data.  You could try exporting it to a termporary CSV and querying it from there - I think that's less temperamental than trying to query from excel.